New nx angular component doesn't trigger a build on changes
Using Angular v17.3.0 and "@nx/angular": "18.2.1" in our app.
Perhaps there's something I'm missing in the nx library, but in terms of "watching" for changes - I have added a new component, but it doesn't trigger a rebuild when I make modifications on the HTML/ts files.
e.g. npx nx g @nx/angular:component my-test  --directory .\libs\octave-ui\src\lib\my-test\my-test
And of course I've already served my app with npx nx serve my-web-client
FYI: The existing code DOES trigger changes, but any "untracked" git changes don't trigger a rebuild.

I wish I knew what I'm missing here. Perhaps something in the nx.json config ?

Here are few things that you can try, I would suggest you to first check the nx.json & workspace.json.
If the above file looks good, try increase the file watching limit.
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npx nx serve my-web-client

Additionally try clearing the cache "npx nx reset" I believe these steps should resolve your issue.
Incase you still face issue after clearing your cache, try to track all the changes to git.
"git add .\libs\octave-ui\src\lib\my-test\my-test"
If nothing works try rebuilding manually.
"npx nx build my-web-client"
Hope this helps.

Okay so the issue is that I'm new to the v17/18  standalone components, where there are NO modules to deal with. So if I DON'T import my new component into its parent, for example, then Angular doesn't know anything about it. Once I found a home for it via the parent's "import", the rebuild worked as expected.
